# jQuery binding issue after ajax - using $(document).on('submit'

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im having an issue with jQuery losing its binding to a class after an ajax update. Ive done this before, and CANT NOT find where my issue is, so im asking for help.

I have a form:

```
<div id="confirmed_tile">
<form id="form_id" name="form_name" class='whatsdone'>
</table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Name
        </td>
        <td>
        Name
        </td>
        <td>
        Name
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="press_submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Then I have some jquery that handles the form submittion:

```
$(document).on('submit','.whatsdone',function(){
    var url = "ajax/update_appointment_clinic.php"; 
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $( this ).serialize(), 
               success: function(data)
               {
                   $( "div#confirmed_tile" ).html(data);
               }
             });
        return false; 
});
```

This ajax call both submits the form for updating mysql, and echo's back the form with the updated info and sends back to the page with the form on it.

This is all working great, but once I submit and ajax updates the div, the ajax call no longer works. I know this is because of an issue with the form class losing it binding to the jquery function, but I thought my choice of `$(document).on('submit','.whatsdone',function()` would solve this issue. It does not. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Responce data back from ajax:

```
<table width='100%' border='0' id='large' cellspacing='0' class='tablesorter table'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th rowspan='3'><p>Time</p></th>
<th rowspan='1'><p>First</p></th>
<th rowspan='1'><p>Last</p></th>
<th rowspan='2'><p>Pet Name</p></th>
<th rowspan='4'><p>APT</p></th>
<th rowspan='4'><p>Species</p></th>
<th rowspan='4'><p>Phone #</p></th>
<th rowspan='4'><p>Status</p></th>
<th rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</th>
<th rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</th>
<th rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                                 


<tr>
<td><p>2:00 pm</p></td>
<td><p>B</p></td>
<td><p>Bozley</p></td>
<td><p>Holly</p></td>
<td><p>(233)</p></td>
<td><p>Canine</p></td>
<td><p>555-555-5555</p></td>
<form name='6' method='post' class='whatsdone'>
<input type='hidden' name='app_id' value='6'>
<input type='hidden' name='clinic_id' value='20'>
<input type='hidden' name='appointment_date' value='2015-02-05'>
<input type='hidden' name='first_visit_apt' value='233'>
<td style='max-width:100px'><p>
   <select name='confirm_value'>
   <option value='1'><p>Confirmed</p></option>
   <option value=5>Left Voicemail</option>
   <option value=4>Left Message w/ Person</option>
   <option value=3>Rescheduled</option>
   <option value=1>Confirmed</option>
   <option value=0>Unconfirmed</option>
   <option value=2>Cancelled</option>
   <option value=6>Could Not Reach</option>
   </select></p>
</td>
<td style='max-width:30px'>
<input type='submit' data-form='6' class='update_confirmed_button' value='GO'>
</td>
</form>
<td style='max-width:30px'><p>11:11 pm</p></td>
<td style='max-width:30px'>
<div class='color_5' title='Participant with responce'>
<div style='display:none'>5</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you
Jason

Comment: It's really hard to answer this type of question without more information. A fiddle or jsbin would be good. Just to start, this doesn't look like it would do anything because `$( "div#confirmed_tile" )` doesn't maych anything in the html you provide (did you mean `cancelled_tile`?)

Comment: My bad, mistake on entering question, I fixed. On my server, the div's match and this does work, once, it just wont work again after ajax updates the div. - What more info can I provide?

Comment: my thoughts exactly.. the div that you're replacing `confirmed_tile` and the div you have in html `cancelled_tile` did not match. So is that a mistake or you have some oter div with that id

Comment: can u confirm if the form returned as `data` in Ajax call has the same class  `whatsdone` ?

Comment: Is the form still there after the AJAX request has returned a value? And does it still have the class "whatsdone". If so, then your .on() listener should be working.  Have you tried putting a `console.log('test')` at the start of the function, so not in the AJAX request but before it and checking whether it is called at all. Also you could try using `$('body').on()` instead of `$(document).on()`, although this is just a hunch.

Comment: Yes, the same class is on the data that updates the div. The data returned from the ajax call.

Comment: Make a fiddle or jsbin. If your problem doing that is with the ajax call, just replace the `div` with some static content and see if you can still catch events. If you get through that process, you may solve the problem yourself. If not, we'll be able to provide better help.

Comment: I added console.log('test') before the ajax call, inside the listener., It fires the first time, and DOES NOT fire the second time.. I have confirmed again that after the ajax update, the class .whatsdone is still inside the form.

Comment: Can you show us your ajax _data_ response?!

Comment: I updated my question with a sample response data.

Comment: in your response, `form` is inside `tr` but not inside any `td`. I don't think it's a well formed HTML. Also in your original div, you have a `form` which has a `table` inside it but in Ajax response, you have `form` inside `table` that too not properly placed as i mentioned before. Try changing it back to your original structure i.e., `form` with a `table` not the other way around :)

Comment: You are right about the formatting.. I fixed it, but it had no impact on my issue.

Comment: i just tried binding some handler on some improperly placed html like yours but it's working for me, so i guess that's not the issue.. by the way do u see any console errors ?

Comment: atleast now we've a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zidopubafe/1/edit?html,output) to replicate this issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70325/discussion-between-arkantos-and-jason).

Comment: the issue is because of improper html.. `form` is getting closed in the beginning itself without including any `input` elements including `submit`. Thats y clicking on that not doing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, issue is with improper html, because of which `form` is closed without including any `input` elements. I've edited the structure like below and it works :) Here's the [bin](http://jsbin.com/kifipijagi/1/edit?html,output) to verify

```
<form name='6' method='post' class='whatsdone'>
<input type='hidden' name='app_id' value='6'>
<input type='hidden' name='clinic_id' value='20'>
<input type='hidden' name='appointment_date' value='2015-02-05'>
<input type='hidden' name='first_visit_apt' value='233'>


<table width='100%' border='0' id='large' cellspacing='0' class='tablesorter table'>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th rowspan='3'><p>Time</p></th>
  <th rowspan='1'><p>First</p></th>
  <th rowspan='1'><p>Last</p></th>
  <th rowspan='2'><p>Pet Name</p></th>
  <th rowspan='4'><p>APT</p></th>
  <th rowspan='4'><p>Species</p></th>
  <th rowspan='4'><p>Phone #</p></th>
  <th rowspan='4'><p>Status</p></th>
  <th rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</th>
  <th rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</th>
  <th rowspan='4'>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                                 
 <tr>
  <td><p>2:00 pm</p></td>
  <td><p>B</p></td>
  <td><p>Bozley</p></td>
  <td><p>Holly</p></td>
  <td><p>(233)</p></td>
  <td><p>Canine</p></td>
  <td><p>555-555-5555</p></td>
  <td style='max-width:100px'>
     <select name='confirm_value'>
      <option value='1'><p>Confirmed</p></option>
      <option value=5>Left Voicemail</option>
      <option value=4>Left Message w/ Person</option>
      <option value=3>Rescheduled</option>
      <option value=1>Confirmed</option>
      <option value=0>Unconfirmed</option>
      <option value=2>Cancelled</option>
      <option value=6>Could Not Reach</option>
   </select>
 </td>
 <td style='max-width:30px'>
  <input type='submit' data-form='6' class='update_confirmed_button' value='GO'>
 </td>

  <td style='max-width:30px'><p>11:11 pm</p></td>
  <td style='max-width:30px'>
    <div class='color_5' title='Participant with responce'>
       <div style='display:none'>5</div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</form>
```

EDIT: Capturing values of multiple users and do an Ajax post for that user alone.You can remove `form` and all hidden `input` elements. We shall make use of data-* attributes for this

```
<input type='submit' 
       data-user='{ 
          "app_id" : "6",
          "clinic_id" : "20",
          "appointment_date" : "2015-02-05",
          "first_visit_apt" : "233"
       }'
       data-form='6'   
       class='update_confirmed_button postBtn' value='GO'>
```

Just register a handler for that to fire the ajax call

```
   $(document).on('click','.postBtn',function(e){
      var postData = $(e.target).data('user');
      // append if any params
      $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax/update_appointment_clinic.php',
            data : postData,
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data){
                 // deal with ajax response
            }
      });
   });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: In case this solves your issue, feel free to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: So, doing this DID solve my issue, but I cant do my project like this. ISSUE IS: I need the form inside the while loop so there is one form PER person displayed.  Im not sure why It wont work with the form inside the while loop?  So, knowing that this solved my issue, but also that I need the form inside the while loop so there is one form per line, what can I do?

Comment: you can even change `submit` to `button` now that you're removing `form` to make it a valid HTML